# SSIS Data Source Data Type Split

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I manage data from an Excel template using two distinct packages, each tailored to handle variations in column data type settings for an Excel template. Although the layout of the Excel file remains consistent, the date column often presents challenges with users inputting data in either date, general format or, text format .

For this specific issue, here are the output column setting below:
Package A's Excel source output column set as DT_WSTR
Package B's Excel source output column set as Date

In SQL Server, the data type is set to NVARCHAR(255)

Is it possible to combine the two package? Let's say if SSIS detected the column is DT_WSTR then run package A, if it detects the column is Date then run package B?

Comment: Unless SSIS does something magical, Excel doesn't have a column format, it has a cell format, so it's still possible to mix dates and text in a single file, you might as well handle everything as string and mangle it to date later

Answer (score 0):

You need to first define a column in your excel data to see if It is a text or date entry :

[image: Excel ScreenShot]

Then SSIS can handle the rest of the task! Lets go step by step in Data Flow Task:
[image: General Package View]

Create an Excel Source to get the data.

Insert a [conditional split task] into your pipeline, send it down to different paths according to condition imposed on the comment column in the source data. I call the output names as Text and Date, respectively.

[image: Conditional Split]

Finally Create 2 destination OLEDB Task

First OLE-DB Destination --Stack_Date

[image: SDF]

Second OLE-DB Destination --Stack_Text

[image: SWERRT]

Please do not forget to set the data types in your destination table according to your needs.

I defined them as below:

sp_help '[dbo].[Stack_Date]'

[image: DT_DATE]

sp_help '[dbo].[Stack_Text]'

[image: ased]

I hope This is something you are looking for! Stay Safe :)